# where to find old easyphp versions to run old sites

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, easyphp, tiki-wiki

I have old applications which cannot run any more on my new OVH hosting because of php and mysql version probably.
But a want to make  them run again with their data by upgrading the tools (Joomla abd tikiwiki)
So, I have to create an (or several) old webhosting on my computer to make them run again and upgrade using the upgrades for these applications, involved Joomla (version running in 2007) and tikiwiki (6.3 - 2013).

Because I was using for development Easyphp (adapted) on a webserver which is now out, I am seeking for old easyphp versions to install the old webserver environments.

Best regards

Trebly

Answer (score 1):

You can install a recent version of EasyPHP and downgrade the php version.
Check this link: [upgrade or downgrade php version on easyphp for windows](https://dannyherran.com/2015/11/this-is-how-you-upgrade-the-php-version-on-easyphp-for-windows/) for more instructions

Comment: Thanks. I will see now to which version we can downgrade. No problem for Tikiwiki (6.2 ou 6.3) but for Joomla (2007) I must seek forward.

Answer (score 0):

Each upgrade Joomla and Tiki had since 2007 (major or minor) contains hundreds of security fix committed by their respective community members.

It is not advised at all to have such old app running on public hosting and I wouldn’t fell safe to have such website with data in the open (or on the same machine than my own websites).

Make sure you restrict access.